# Many one-to-one tables, enforce only one relationship

Tags: sql, many-to-many, html-lists, one-to-one

I have a problem designing a new database. I feel like it’s probably obvious and surely addressed by others but I can’t find the right search terms.

A simplified (relevant) schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `asset` (
  `asset_id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `serial_num` varchar(255) UNIQUE,
  `site_id` int,
  `type_id` int
);

CREATE TABLE `device` (
  `asset_id` int PRIMARY KEY,
  `device_subtype` varchar(255),
  `ip_address` varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE `peripheral_device` (
  `asset_id` int PRIMARY KEY,
  `per_device_subtype` varchar(255)
```

I either need to use the field asset.type_id to a join table and create a many-to_many relationship. Or I need to create many one-to-one relationships. The tables `device` and `peripheral_device` are types of asset. Because each type of asset has vastly different fields, they don't work in one large table. A small example is of a device that has an IP address and one that does not. But this extends to the operating system on a computer, type of line on a telephone and so on.

The problem with the one-to-one relationship(s) is that multiple tables means more than one table could have the foreign key in it, but we can't have more than one device type per `asset_id`. Is it possible to enforce a single entry in only one table? How is this usually handled? It can't be a unique problem?

EDIT
Alternative option:

```
CREATE TABLE `asset` (
  `asset_id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` int,
  `pdevice_id` int,
  `serial_num` varchar(255) UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE `peripheral_device` (
  `pdevice_id` int PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE `network_device` (
  `asset_id` int PRIMARY KEY,
);

ALTER TABLE `asset` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `device` (`device_id`);

ALTER TABLE `asset` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`pdevice_id`) REFERENCES
```

`peripheral_device` (`pdevice_id`);

Comment: Nothing in your data refers to "device type", so I am confused about your question.

Comment: `device`  and `peripheral_device` are both device types. 
Alternatively, `type_id` could refer to a many-to-many relationship defining the device's type.

Comment: You could remove the `asset_id` from the other tables and instead add `device_id` and `peripheral_device_id` to `asset`. Then use a check constraint to make sure an asset has one of the IDs set and the other null.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner that would be cumbersome and create a lot of white space/unused fields. This is a simplified version but if this were scalable then there is potential for very many of those tables. To include them in the first table makes that table huge and a waste of space. This is the crux of the problem.

Comment: Space? How many billions of assets do you have in your database that you must worry about some nulls stored?

Comment: But well, this is indeed a common problem without a perfect solution. Maybe some opject orientated database instead of a common RDBMS offers a solution.

Comment: So even if the only fields that are shared are `serial_num`, `site_id` and `type_id` and have10+ unique fields, you would still use one table?

Comment: Ok fair enough. But it's for SQL course. So, limited.
To b clear, I picked the data and this is not the specific problem required by the course.

Comment: Would I do this? I don't know. Maybe, yes. A common other solution to this is a key value table, but that's something I would avoid. Erm, stop, one table? I am suggesting to use your three tables but link the tables the other way round.

Comment: Ah, did not read correctly. Do you mean to use multiple foreign keys?

Comment: Yes, the table asset would have IDs to the other tables and a check constraint assures only one ID is used.

Comment: Ok, best option so far